# How many times update maximum gets called when trying to find the running maximum in a randomized array of numbers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, random, statistics

Suppose we have an array with integers -N to N in an array size of 2N + 1. We first shuffle the elements in the array, then try to find the maximum integer by iterating through the array from the first element to the last element: (code example is in Java)

```
int called = 0;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i : array) {
    if (i > max) {
        called++;
        max = i;
    }
}
```

What is the expectation(average over many runs) of value `called` after iterating through the array?

Edit:

How I found it to be close to ln(array.length):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) list.add(i);

    int called = 0;
    int runs = 100;

    for (int i = 1; i <= runs; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        int max = -1;
        for (int num : list) {
            if (num > max) {
                called++;
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Expectation: " + called/runs);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking the expected average off called?  Because the value could be anything from 1 to 2N+1.    Sounds more like a math problem rather than a programming problem as well.  Have you tried it a few times to see what the result is?  Also please provide a full working sample of the code, and specify which language you are using.

Comment: Yes the average value. The result seems to be ln(2N+1) but I could not prove that.

Comment: If you are getting (N2+1) you are not randomizing your array correctly as that is the size of your array.  You should be getting an average of (N / 2).

Comment: ln(2N+1) != 2N+1 != N2+1

Comment: Your code does not match your description.  You said an array of integers from -N to N.  So size 2N+1.  The above is a fixed array of 1000000 containing 0 to 999999.

Comment: @wz366: Here's a hint: The [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) converges to ln(N)+γ (where [γ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) is less than 0.6). There's an easy recursive construction which makes the above statement relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider randomly shuffled array. We want to estimate K - number of times than i-th element is bigger than all of its predecessors.

Expected value of K equals to sum of probabilities that i-th element is bigger than all its predecessors. E(K) = Σ<sub>1</sub><sup>2N+1</sup> P<sub>i</sub>.

Now we want to find P<sub>i</sub>. Consider prefix of length i for our array. Probability that the last element in the prefix is the biggest is 1/i. So we have P<sub>i</sub> = 1/i.

Consequently:E(K) = Σ<sub>1</sub><sup>2N+1</sup>1/i. We can estimate this sum via definite integral as ln(2N+1)+O(1).

#### So, the answer is ln(2N+1)+O(1).

And Monte-Carlo simulation for kinda proof:

```
constexpr size_t N = 1000;
std::array<int, 2 * N + 1> arr;
std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), -N);
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
double moving = 0;
for (double trial = 1; trial < 10001; ++trial) {
    std::shuffle(arr.begin(), arr.end(), g);
    int called = 0;
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            ++called;
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    if (trial > 1) {
        moving = moving * ((trial - 1) / trial) + called / trial;
    }
    else {
        moving = called;
    }
}
cout << "actual:   " << moving << endl;
cout << "expected: " << std::log(2 * N + 1) << " + O(1)" << endl;
```

> ```
> actual:   8.1581   
> expected: 7.6014 + O(1)
> ```

Comment: Cool, that's a good way to show it. As I alluded to in a comment on the question, the O(1) in your equation converges to the Euler-Mascheroni constant, which is around .577. However, there is an off-by-one error in your test, which ignores the first element of the array. That's not totally unreasonable since you might compute max that way, but you would have to initialise `max = arr[0];` in order to get the right answer. Also, in that case your analysis would be incorrect, since the sum (or integral) should then start at 2, not 1...

Comment: Fixing that error produces a much closer approximation to ln(2N+1)+γ.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I came across this problem during a software engineer interview. Here is what I found that could be used to solve this problem:

[Cycle Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation)

[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)

As Yola and rici have pointed out, the answer should be ln(n) + γ (where γ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant and n is the number of elements in the array).