# MinMax Algorithm Time Complexity Analysis

Tags: algorithm, performance, complexity-theory, analysis

I am trying to analyse a nested version of a minmax algorithm.

```
ALGORITHM MaxMin2(A[0..n − 1], MaxValue, MinValue)

MaxValue ← A[0]
MinValue ← A[0]

for i ← 1 to n − 1 do
    if A[i] > MaxValue
        MaxValue ← A[i]
    else
        if A[i] < MinValue
            MinValue ← A[i]
```

It seems clear to me that this requires 2n - 2 comparisons, but apparently this nested version of the algorithm results in 2n - ln n - 1 comparisons. Could anyone explain how this comes about?

Comment: The statements inside the loop do not change its conditions or cause it to break prematurely, hence the loop will always execute `n - 1` times, i.e. it will always be `O(n)`. That's all time complexity analysis requires; no need to precisely quantify each operation.

Comment: What about average-case efficiency?

Comment: Keyword: *always*. That means worst-case = average-case = best-case = `O(n)`.

Comment: The `ln(n)` is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267640). The expectation is that `A[i] > MaxValue` will be true approximately `ln(n)` times. When the first condition is true, the second comparison is skipped, so the total number of comparisons is slightly reduced.